# Add two lists in java8?

Tags: java, arrays, list, stream, concatenation

I am trying to add two lists together in java 8.
Both lists are coming from separate objects in the json but I want to put them into a new object together in the java code.

I have tried listUtils.union but this is adding to the new object as two arrays.
The addAll method and stream .concat() are also giving errors.

Example:

Json has:

“Object 1”: [{ test:”2”
}]

“Object 2”: [{ test:”2”
}]

Trying to add to a hash map into the object “newobject” but I have to call methods to get the new lists.

For example :

Newlist = listUtils.Union(addobject1(), addObject1) (these are the method names that return my lists from the json.

put(“newobject”, newlist)

Any suggestions ?

Comment: This question would be clearer with more code and _especially_ the types of the variables you're working with.  Getting the types right is probably 90% of the work here.

Comment: They are all strings

Comment: So are they stored as `List<String>`?  Are the strings the individual elements, or are they JSON strings that have to be parsed?

Comment: Yes they are list<String> and Ive looped through them adding them to a list variable which I then want to add together to the second object that Ive handled in the same way .

Comment: @Yankeecandle why don't you [edit and update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64177811/edit) your question respectively? Provide, at least, some snippet, please. Also, have you at least tried to Google for the solution? I'm pretty sure there are dozens of examples available online, on how to merge/join two lists.

Comment: Yes I have googled all options and am receiving build errors which is why Ive asked for the help here

Comment: Is there anything special about the union of these two lists?  If the lists are of size `n` and `m` is the final list of size `n+m` or does some reduction take place?

Answer (score 1):

According to the JSON string, you have lists of some POJO:

```java
class MyPojo {
    private final String test;

    public MyPojo(String t) {this.test = t; }

    public String getTest() {return test; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{ test: " + test + "}";
    }
}
```

Then `object1` and `object2` are the input lists and there are several ways to merge them:

1. Using `Stream.concat`

```java
Stream.concat(object1.stream(), object2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

2. Using `Stream.of`

```java
Stream.of(object1, object2)
      .flatMap(List::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

3. Using `addAll`

```java
List<MyPojo> result = new ArrayList<>(object1);
result.addAll(object2);
```

4. Streaming list of lists

```java
Arrays.asList(object1, object2)
      .stream()
      .flatMap(List::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```